# I am getting a null point error when initializing an array grid of objects

Tags: java, arrays, grid-layout

I am trying to initialize an array grid of objects and get a null point error when I do so. It should be calling the object Constructor in Cell each iteration of the loop.  Instead I am getting the error. Please help.

```
public class Spread extends JPanel {
    private JPanel outputArea;
    private JTextArea numberDead;
    private JTextArea totalInfected;
    private JTextArea newInfections;
    private Integer totalDead;
    private Integer total;
    private Integer newInfected;
    private Integer length = 60;
    private Integer width = 100;
    private Cell[][] label;
    
    public void makeOutputArea() {
        int a;
        int b;
        outputArea = new JPanel(new GridLayout(length, width, -1, -1));
        outputArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));

        for (a = 0; a < (length - 1); a++){
            for (b = 0; b < (width - 1); b++)
                label[a][b] = new Cell(); //nullpointerror is located here.
                label[a][b].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
                label[a][b].setOpaque(true);
                outputArea.add(label[a][b]);
                outputArea.setVisible(true);
                if (label[a][b].getInfected() == true) ++total;
            }
        }
    
    public JPanel getOutputArea() {
        return outputArea;
    }
...Additional code follows.
```

This is the Cell class it should be initializing in the array. As you can see it has a constructor, which should be called for each loop.  Instead it is giving a null pointer and never initializing each cell object.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Cell extends JLabel{
    private int iteration;
    private boolean infected;
    private boolean dead;
    private boolean immune;
    private Random generator = new Random(); //Random number Generator
    private static int infectionRate = 5;
    private static int deathRate = 3;
    
    
    public void setIteration(int i) {
        iteration = i;
    }
    
    public int getIteration() {
        return iteration;
    }
    
    public void setInfected(boolean b) {
        infected = b;
    }
    
    public boolean getInfected() {
        return infected;
    }
    
    public void setDead(boolean a) {
        dead = a;
    }
    
    public boolean getDead() {
        return dead;
    }
    
    public void setImmune(boolean i) {
        immune = i;
    }
    
    public boolean getImmune() {
        return immune;
    }
    
    public Cell() {
        setImmune(false);
        setDead(false);
        setIteration(0);
        if (generator.nextInt(100) < infectionRate) {
            setInfected(true);
            setIteration(++iteration);
        }
        else setInfected(false);
        color();
    }
    
    public void color() {
        if (getInfected() == true) setBackground(Color.RED);
        else if (getDead() == true) setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        else setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    
    public void updateInfection(boolean b) {
        try {
            if (getImmune() == true) return;
            else if (getDead() == true) return;
            else if (getInfected() == true) {
                setIteration(++iteration);
                if (iteration >=4) {
                    if (generator.nextInt(100) < deathRate) {
                        setInfected(false);
                        setDead(true);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        setInfected(false);
                        setImmune(true);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (generator.nextInt(100) <= 75) {
                    setInfected(true);
                    setIteration(++iteration);
                    return;
                }
                else return;
            }
        }
        finally {
            this.color();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Also, if you ask for debug advice and your code is throwing an exception, you should always include the full stack trace and highlight the line throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cell [][] label` is a two-dimentional array in java.
So you have to allocate the memory for it first.

Only then you can execute code like:

```
label[a][b] = new Cell();
```

This is a lot of information about how to correctly allocate memory to 2-dimensional arrays in java, quick googling reveals [this tutorial](https://condor.depaul.edu/ggordon/courses/211/212doc/TwoDimensionalArrays.htm#:%7E:text=In%20Java%2C%20we%20represent%20these%20as%20two%20dimensional%20arrays.&text=int%20%5B%20%5D%5B%20%5D%20table%20%3D%20new,dimensional%20array%20as%20row%20major.)